# How to get correspondence information between the meso-skeleton and boundary mesh in CGAL:mcfskel

Tags: graphics, cgal

I am new to CGAL and currently working on CGAL Triangulated Surface Mesh Skeletonization.

Based on the examples in CGAL docs, I know how to get the correspondence information between the skeleton (curve) vertices and boundary (input) mesh vertices. However, what I need is the correspondence information for meso-skeleton phase (i.e. before converting it into curve skeleton). Hope you guys can help me out on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an undocumented feature, meaning the API may be subject to changes.
The vertices of the meso-skeleton have a vector of vertex descriptor of the input mesh corresponding to it.

```
typedef Mean_curvature_flow_skel::Meso_skeleton Meso_skeleton;
boost::graph_traits<Meso_skeleton>::vertex_descriptor v=...;// a vertex of the meso skeleton
std::vector<boost::graph_traits<Input_mesh>::vertex_descriptor>& correspondances = v->vertices;
```